# Android finish() StartActivityForResult not working

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult, close-application

I have a problem in Android with the finish() function:

I am trying to obtain the following behavior: when the user lunches the application for the first time, I want to start a wizard procedure. I am using a PageViewer with different fragmets. I want that the application closes, if the user presses the back button while it is in the first page.

Here what I did:

In the **main activity** I check if the user has started the application for the first time. If this is the case, then I start a **new activity** (the wizard)

```
if(firstTime) {
    // here activity is the main activity
    Intent i = new Intent(activity, Wizard.class);
    activity.startActivityForResult(i,0);
}
```

**In the wizard activity class** I override the onBackPressed method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(pager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        setResult(5);
        finish();
    } else{
        // code
    }
}
```

When finish() is called, Android invokes the onActivityResult method of the parent activity (the main activity):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(resultCode == 5) {
        finish()
    } 
}
```

What I expect is the application to be closed. What I get is that Android calls onResume and, then, onCreate methods, starting the wizard from the beginning. Then, if from this new wizard I press back again, the application closes as expected.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of `finish();` for exiting whole application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Your previous activity which was in background might be coming in foreground by your code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great! Of cours I didn't think to start the home screen. What will happen if I finish() the main activity before starting the Wizard? I will try.

Thank you ;)

Comment: Ok, finishing the MainActivity just after I started the wizard activity, solves the problem.